# Why do I get different values for information for a same timeframe from different timeframe?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to get the close bar (from the right) with have more volume than previous one in the daily timeframe.

Given this code:

```
getLastStrength(simple string period) =>
    volumen = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, period, volume)
    _count = 1
    _found = false
    while not _found and _count < 10
        if (volumen[_count] > volumen[_count+1])
            _found := true
        else
            _count := _count + 1
    _count

string texto = "D:"+ str.tostring(getLastStrength("1D"))
if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, texto, color= color.red)
```

I get different values if I run it from a daily timeframe or from 4h one (see screenshots)
[image]
[image]

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop iterates on each bar per the chart's timeframe.

```
while not _found and _count < 10
    if (volumen[_count] > volumen[_count+1])
        _found := true
    else
        _count := _count + 1
```

On the 1D chart, at each iteration, `volumen[_count]` points at different days' volume.

On the 4h chart, over up to 6 iterations, `volumen[_count]` can point at the same day's volume (4*6=24).